# Scroll an element by dragging, similar to touch devices …

Tags: javascript, html, css-grid

Consider the following layout, that displays 5x4 squares, some are hidden from the view but the remaining ones can be viewed by dragging …

It seems with the following grid layout I’m unable to scroll left/right yet up/down works fine, and I’m confused why this would be happening?

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #046;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto auto auto auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Html:

```
<body>
  <div class="bottom" id="bottom">
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('bottom');

element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (event.buttons == 1) {
    if (Math.abs(event.movementX) > Math.abs(event.movementY)) {
      if (event.movementX > 0) element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft - event.movementX;
      if (event.movementX < 0) element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft - event.movementX;
    } else {
      if (event.movementY > 0) element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop - event.movementY;
      if (event.movementY < 0) element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop - event.movementY;
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bw6vnxtL/

Comment: Somewhat unclear what your question is. You speak of JavaScript but have none.  And, " element is offset by 10pt from left and top?" really describes "margin" to me here.  Perhaps you can clarify and add whatever code you have tried so we can assist you in fixing in here - what do you mean but "scroll".  I know what scroll is but in this context what you desire is not clear.

Comment: FWIW your HTML could be much less with CSS but I do understand not all uses of HTML are on a web page and sometimes CSS does not get applied properly - like in some mail clients with HTML have challenges etc.

Comment: ...is there a reason you aren't using an _actual_ CSS `grid`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution ...

Adjust the width to 100vw, and apply width to each element so 4 out of 5 will show at a time:

```
.bottom {
  width: 100vw;
}

.bottom > div {
  width: calc(100vw / 4);
}
```